# #selector doesn't see my own created method in NSMenuItem

Tags: swift, macos, swift4

I have a problem creating a `NSMenuItem` actions, I have created function, which creates Menu for me, while using init on `NSMenuItem` with selector, my described function doesn't work on swift 4, if I use `NSApp.terminate` - `NSMenuItem` sees selector works normally()... Here is the code:

```
mainMenuController: NSObject {
  func setUpMenus(){
  //...
  let firstItemMainMenu = NSMenuItem.init(title: "Test", action: #selector(test), keyEquivalent: "") // This one doesn't work
  let fourthItemMainMenu = NSMenuItem.init(title: "Quit", action: #selector(NSApp.terminate), keyEquivalent: "q") //This one NSApp.terminate - works
  //...
}
```

and here is the function:

```
@objc func test(_ sender: Any?){
    let alert = NSAlert()
    alert.addButton(withTitle: "test")
    alert.messageText = "test"
    alert.runModal()
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the `test` method defined? In which class?

Comment: You also need to set the `target` property of the menu item, so that Cocoa knows where to dispatch the selector.

Comment: it is defined in same class as the setUpMenus()

Setting target doesn't do any help :/

Comment: to be clear...in your posted code `fourthItemMainMenu` works, but `firstItemMainMenu` does not?

Comment: Yes. if I move that NSApp.terminate to firstItem selector, then firstItem works and fourth doesn't, where is something to do with method, I don't know why, but selector is unable to recognize it

Comment: @ErnestasŠeputis Ever figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1. Use the syntax `Selector("terminate:")` which hands the selector over to `First Responder` (you will get a warning to use `#selector` syntax)
2. Create an extra method `@objc func quit` which calls `NSApp.terminate`